# How to filll dropdown value using REST API

Tags: rest

I have tried following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetEmpName, "sp.js");
 });

 function GetEmpName() {
   var strUser = "Developer";
    var soapEnv =
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Employee Biodata</listName> \
                    <query><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + strUser + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></query>\
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                            <FieldRef Name='Name' /> \
                        </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
                </soapenv:Envelope>";


    $.ajax({

        url: "http://DOMAIN/LISTNAME/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}
function processResult(xData, status) 
{
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() 
    {

     });

}
```

Department:

I dont know what to write in processResult() to fill dropdown.Please help me out

Comment: The question a bit confuses me, you are asking about REST API but providing SOAP services example

Answer (score 0):

Your `processResult` function should be like:

```
function processResult(xData, status) 
{
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
        var drpValue = $(this).attr("ows_Name").toString();
        var drpValueId = $(this).attr("ows_Name").toString();
        $("#ddlCategory").append($("<option></option>").val(drpValueId).html(drpValue));
    });
}
```

Note that `#ddlCategory` should be your dropdown ID.